# Search in part of the list by LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I want to know if there's a way to search from a specific **index** in **LINQ**

This is what i want to do for example :

```
 //search after the 4th element if exist any true
     bool result = myList.Any(a=>a.flagTodo) 
// in my case I want to do like:  myList.where(a=>a.index >4).Any(a=>a.flagTodo)
```

there's any way to do it in the same linq ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable.Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) to bypass specified number of elements in sequence:

```
bool result = myList.Skip(4).Any(a => a.flagTodo);
```

**BTW** *you don't need to verify list length* - if there is less than 4 items, result will be false - `Skip(4)` will return empty sequence. And `Any` returns `false` because none of elements in sequence satisfies condition (sequence is empty).

Answer (score 4):

You can skip the first 4 elements.

```
 bool result = myList.Skip(4).Any(a => a.flagTodo);
```

But you need to check on your list length first before calling this statement.

Answer (score 0):

Either use `Skip` as others have mentioned or pass the index so that you can use it in `Any`

```
bool result = myList.Select((obj, index) => new { obj, index })
                    .Any(x => x.index > 4 && x.obj.flagTodo);
```